# how to kill previous tasks when a new asynctask is called

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

i am using asynctask to fetch images from given url.these images are displaying in a listview.the problem is when i am scrolling the list view fast the app is crashing.logcat error is

```
03-27 13:08:42.355: E/AndroidRuntime(25567): java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: pool=128/128, queue=10/10
```

from this error i came to know that it is the problem of running many asynctask threads parallely.to solve this issue i have written the below code.

```
   NWTaskObj obj = new NWTaskObj();
            obj.setType(AdapterType.OfferAdapter);
            obj.setLink(offer.getImageLink());
            obj.setObject(this);
            if(count<10){
            new HandleOfferImage().execute(obj); 
            }else{
            new HandleOfferImage().cancel(true);
            new HandleOfferImage().execute(obj); 
            }
```

**count** is a static variable.it is incremented in HandleOfferImage class.but still it is crashing in the same scenario.i need to kill the previous asynctasks(if count >10) except last but one.i dont want to use lazy list here.can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having more than one task and want to cancel all the tasks, its very simple. Just store all the async tasks which you are starting in ArrayList. And when you want to cancel these tasks, just iterate over this ArrayList and cancel all the tasks. Simple. Like:

```
HandleOfferImage myAsyncTask = new HandleOfferImage();
aList.add(myAsyncTask); //aList is you array list
myAsyncTask.execute(obj);

//When you want to cancel
for(HandleOfferImage task : aList) {
    task.cancel();
}
```

Comment: i dont want to cancel every asynctasks.i want to cancel asynctasks except current and last but one.

Comment: i have made some changes to your answer and it is working fine.posted the answer here.

Answer (score 1):

```
new HandleOfferImage().cancel(true);
```

is wrong. hold task pointer in a variale like mTask and then

```
mTask.cancel(true);
```

UPDATE:

```
if (mTask!= null) {
    mTask.cancel(true);
}

mTask= new TaskGetTeams();
mTask.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintain boolean variable like **isloggedin** in Application class.Make true the  **isloggedin** flag where you want to start Task and false **isloggedin** flag where you want to stop the task.Check this **isloggedin** flag tat each level in your task.Execute your task if your **isloggedin** flag ytrue only otherwise don't execute your task and comeout from task.

Answer (score 0):

Moreover, you need to check in doBackground() whether the asynctask is cancelled or not.

From developer site.

> Cancelling a task

A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking cancel(boolean). Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to isCancelled() to return true. After invoking this method, onCancelled(Object), instead of onPostExecute(Object) will be invoked after doInBackground(Object[]) returns. To ensure that a task is cancelled as quickly as possible, you should always check the return value of isCancelled() periodically from doInBackground(Object[]), if possible (inside a loop for instance.)

Answer (score 0):

Taking boolean variable.

```
boolean stopTask = false,isDoing = true;
```

Suppose this is your `AsyncTask`

```
public class HandleOfferImage extends AsyncTask
{
      public void doInBackGround()
      {
           if(stopTask==false)
           {
               isDoing = true;
               // do your stuff
           }
           else
           {
               isDoing = false;
           }

      }
}
```

now in your code,

```
if(count<10){      
            stopTask = true; // stop task
            while(isDoing==true){} // wait to stop
            stopTask = false;
            new HandleOfferImage().execute(obj);       
            }else{      

            new HandleOfferImage().cancel(true);      
            stopTask = true;
            while(isDoing==true){} // wait to stop
            stopTask = false;

            new HandleOfferImage().execute(obj);       
            }
```

This is what I assume can help you, But I have not tested this code myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(count<maxConst){
                task=new HandleOfferImage();
                offerImageTask.add(task);
                task.execute(obj);
            }else{ 
                for(int nCount=0;nCount<offerImageTask.size()-2;nCount++){
                offerImageTask.get(nCount).cancel(true);
                offerImageTask.remove(nCount);

                }
                task=new HandleOfferImage();
                offerImageTask.add(task);
                task.execute(obj);
            }
```

here maxConst=10 and offerImageTask is an arraylist of type HandleOfferImage class.